# Which serialization format does Java use?

Tags: java, rmi

In an RMI program, I want to implement the Serializable interface to serialize objects received from a server. Does Java 6 use a built-in serialization format? I wanted to know if there is a specific name for the serialization format.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, Java has its own [binary serialization format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html). And I don't think it has a name other than *Java serialization [format | protocol]*.

Comment: Not only does it lack a real name, it lacks a real specification. I implemented a deserializer against that spec once, and frequently found myself stuck an an ambiguity or omission in that spec. Ultimately, the specification that mattered was the output of Sun's implementation of serialization!

Comment: Its name is Object Serialization and it has a Specification named accordingly. Agree that it is incomplete, especially a couple of RMI-related aspects.