# Finding the end of a java serialized object in a binary stream

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to to isolate Java serialized objects from a binary stream. I know that all Java serialized objects start with 0xACED, however there doesn't seem to be a trivial way to figure out the end of the object in the stream (no magic end bytes or length fields). Is there a way to do this without having to parse the object?

Comment: It seems to be a proprietary format, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6638094/18573 and the comments

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html). You will certainly have to do _some_ parsing.

Comment: Correction: the stream starts with `0xACED0005`. Each object starts with `0x78`, unless it's one of a number of special cases (String, null, Throwable, reference to already-serialized object...) Testing the consistency of a one-object stream should be a bit simpler than the general case.